# How to stop opening a viewpart in eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am using eclipse RCP. I have an item in a table and when I double click on the item it opens a view . If the user does not have access to the view, then the user cannot open the view.

So I checked for the access rights for the user on the item and I close the perspective.

```
if (!user.hasReadAccess())
    final IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();

for (int w = 0; w < windows.length; w++)
{
    final IWorkbenchPage[] pages = windows[w].getPages();
    for (int p = 0; p < pages.length; p++)
    {
        final IWorkbenchPage page = pages[p];
        //  page.hideView(page.findView(MYViewID));
        final IViewReference[] viewRefs = page.getViewReferences();
        for (int v = 0; v < viewRefs.length; v++)
        {
            for (IPerspectiveDescriptor ipd : page.getOpenPerspectives())
            {
                if (ipd.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(PERSPECTIVE_ID))
                {

                    page.closePerspective(page.getPerspective(), true, true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It hides the perspective but it always opens the perspective and close it immediately.

In other words, even after the `closePerspective()` is called, the `CreatePartControl` method  of the `ViewPart` is still invoked and the user is able to see the view getting opened and closed immediately. What causes this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: I don't understand how opening the view relates to closing a certain perspevtive. BTW could you reformat the code in a sensible way?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a method on IWorkbenchPage that you use to open a view like :

```
public IViewPart showView(String viewId, String secondaryId, int mode)
            throws PartInitException;
```

you should call this method in an if condition saying

```
if ( userHasReadAccess ) {
    page.showView(viewId, secondaryId, IworkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE );
}
```